# Optional savebox with options

Tags: macros, programming, optional-arguments

I'm working on a modified version of the `report.cls` for internal documents that might have a standard disclaimer text included.  Ideally, I'd like to have something like
`\disclaimer{some category}{some entity}` that inserts text on the titlepage when that is present.

Here's what I've tried (to no avail):

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{myclass}
\newcommand{\@disclaimer}[2]{\parbox[b]{0.9\textwidth}{Some legal text referencing
category #1 asserted by person #2}}

\begin{document}

\title{My title}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\disclaimer{123.4}{Attourney Bob} % if this is omitted

%%% Set up the new titlepage format
\newlength{\titlevsep}
\setlength{\titlevsep}{0.6in}
\def\and{\\[0.25\titlevsep]and\\[0.25\titlevsep]}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{../graphics/company_seal.png}\par
\vspace{\titlevsep}
{\huge\bfseries\@title\unskip\strut\par}
\vspace{\titlevsep}
{\large\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author\end{tabular}\par}
\vspace{\titlevsep}
{\large \@date\par}
\vfill
\@disclaimer
\end{titlepage}
}


\maketitle

\section{Important stuff}
blah blah blah ...

\end{document}
```

I think I need something like `\global\let\@disclaimer\@empty` once I have it working so that it won't die on compile if `\disclaimer` is missing.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but I don't know what, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

In your class file you should have something like

```
\let\@disclaimer\@empty % initialize to empty
\newcommand{\disclaimer}[2]{%
  \gdef\@disclaimer{%
    \parbox[b]{0.9\textwidth}{%
      Some legal text referencing
      category #1 asserted by person #2%
    }%
  }%
}
```

and then in the part where you define the processing of the title page

```latex
\vfill
\@disclaimer
\end{titlepage}
```

like you have now.

This would do nothing if the `\disclaimer` command is not used in the actual document, because it has been initialized as `\@empty`, that expands to nothing.

Comment: That worked like a charm!  Thank you for the quick reply.